# How to pass a variable to a Javascript map function

Tags: javascript, json

In the following code I want to replace the {cash} with a variable so that I can return any of the data items from the JSON.  Any idea how to do this?

Javascript:

```
    let chartLabels = arr.map(({date}) => date).reverse();
    let chartData = arr.map(({cash}) => cash).reverse();
```

JSON:

```
    0: "{\"date\":\"2020-03-31\"\"totalAssets\":\"300280000000.00\",\"intangibleAssets\":null,\"earningAssets\":null,\"otherCurrentAssets\":\"5598000000.00\",\"totalLiab\":\"229507000000.00\",\"totalStockholderEquity\":\"58431000000.00\",\"deferredLongTermLiab\":\"734000000.00\",\"otherCurrentLiab\":\"50891000000.00\",\"commonStock\":\"12267000000.00\",\"cash\":\"20305000000.00}"
    1: "{\"date\":\"2019-12-31\",\"totalAssets\":\"306928000000.00\",\"intangibleAssets\":\"482000000.00\",\"earningAssets\":null,\"otherCurrentAssets\":null,\"totalLiab\":\"229599000000.00\",\"totalStockholderEquity\":\"64106000000.00\",\"deferredLongTermLiab\":\"652000000.00\",\"otherCurrentLiab\":\"4531000000.00\",\"commonStock\":\"12267000000.00\",\"cash\":\"25567000000.00}"
    2: "{\"date\":\"2019-09-30\","totalAssets\":\"301016000000.00\",\"intangibleAssets\":\"3652000000.00\",\"earningAssets\":null,\"otherCurrentAssets\":\"7666000000.00\",\"totalLiab\":\"222408000000.00\",\"totalStockholderEquity\":\"65315000000.00\",\"deferredLongTermLiab\":\"558000000.00\",\"otherCurrentLiab\":\"15735000000.00\",\"commonStock\":\"12267000000.00\",\"cash\":\"26994000000.00}"
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? from what I understood, that's pretty simple, take a variable and assign any property value from the JSON. and pass the variable into map. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: You can use destructuring like so: `.map(({[variable]: val}) => val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `({cash}) => cash` you are destructuring the cash from the object.
To access a variable property you can take the whole object and access the property dynamicaly:

```
var variable = 'cash';
arr.map(data => data[variable]).reverse();
```